# Bracing a stud that's been cut too much

Tags: plumbing, framing

I'm installing a bathroom above an existing one, and when running the shower drain pipe I got overzealous without thinking and cut a 3" hole in a 2x4 for the drain (red circle in photo). Only 2 3/8" is allowed by code. How do I brace this to pass inspection? I was thinking about putting 2x8 blocking above and below the cut and then running king studs (with the 4" side facing out) down to the sill plate. Previous builder did something similar (yellow circle). Is that sufficient? This is old construction with 2" actual studs, plus it's at an angle, so I can't just use a stud shoe. Thoughts?

[image: Hi stud]

Comment: You might consider reframing your picture - half of your example in the yellow circle is missing.

Comment: You'll also need to note, that what was once code may no longer be so anything you do that is based upon what you already see may not be current code and could be called out by an inspector.

Comment: Are you just dry-fitting for now? Where's the purple primer??

Comment: Thanks, yeah, just dry-fitting to make sure everything fits! I'm thinking about using this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-CTS-18-in-14-Gauge-Compression-Tension-Strap-CTS218/205325983